Can I use debugger in VSCode to execute Playwright code?
Is it possible to execute playwright code in debug console while you stop the console on breakpoint? Everytime I try to do so, I just get pending promise and nothing happens in the browser. In python, I was able to stop the code and execute and inspect whatever I wanted.
I tried this code and I expected for page to be directed to the "example.com". Instead, I got Promise.
await page.goto("https://example.com")

Promise {
  [[PromiseState]]: 'pending',
  [[PromiseResult]]: undefined,
  Symbol(async_id_symbol): 3147,
  Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol): 145,
  Symbol(kResourceStore): undefined
}


"Can I use debugger in VSCode to execute Playwright code?" Yes. "Is it possible to execute playwright code in debug console while you stop the console on breakpoint?" Yes.

Try setting the breakpoint after the goto if you want to execute it, or step over it to execute the line. I'm not sure how this question relates to Playwright specifically, seems just like "how do I execute a line in debug mode?" in general, correct?
